# Realm (10.1.0) "framework not found realm-sync"

Tags: swift, realm

I use cocoapods to add the latest Realm (10.1.0), and open the .xcworkspace to compile the project directly after completion, and an error message appears when compiling, prompting "framework not found realm-sync". Can someone help me solve this problem?

platform:ios,'11.0’

use_frameworks!
target 'tessss' do
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 10.1.0'
end

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46X7s.png)

Comment: Your podfile is targeting 'tessss'? Also, you should update with 'pod update'

Comment: [This](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6891) may help

Comment: The above answer solved my problem very well, thank you!